# How to convert User-defined class to string

Tags: java, string, object, jakarta-ee

I have a class name "Users" and have 2 elements (int)userId and (String)userName.

```
Users obj1 = new Users(10, "User1");
```

How can I convert the obj1 to string like **"userId: 10, userName: User1"** instead of using

```
obj1.getUserId(), obj1.getUserName()
```

Is there any function or method that I can change it to string like that? Thanks

Comment: override the `toString` method

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement toString method in the Class of Users on your own.

```
public class Users(){
   ...
   public String toString(){
     return "UserId:"+userId+","+"userName:"+userName;
   }
}
```

and use it by calling

```
obj1.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Override the toString() function to return  the string.

```
public String toString() { 
    return "UserId:" + this.UserId + ","+ "UserName:" + this.UserName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a `toString()` method, you don't have to write the code yourself. In `Eclipse`, you can generate the `toString()` with the hot key `Alt + Shift + S`, then click related option. You can use this to generate a `constructor`, `hashCode()` or `equals()` as well.

[image]